# Multiple OpenGL contexts with different APIs

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to use multiple OpenGL contexts simultaneously in [my application](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/exoplanet/id327702034?mt=8). It's a rather messy setup with three OpenGL contexts in three UITableViewCells. The UITableView is itself shown in a UIPopoverView above a fullscreen GLKView (see below). The context in the background is using OpenGL ES 2.0 and the smaller ones on top use OpenGL ES 1.1. The smaller contexts are members of the same sharegroup. The one in the background is not.

Maybe surprisingly, this actually works as intended! And very reliably. I only have a problem with one of the contexts and only very rarely. If I remove this one context, everything works fine. In the rare case, however, I get an exception in the call to `[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];`.

My question is a bit broad, but I'm wondering what I should be looking out for in this situation? Is anyone else using OpenGL ES 1.1 and 2.0 successfully at the same time?

(I looked at the OpenGL ES Analyzer instrument but couldn't find anything that looks severe.)

[image: Screenshot of the Exoplanet App]

Comment: Probably not a 1.1 vs 2.0 issue as those generally can coexist peacefully. Could you have an occasional case where you have the wrong context active when you do the drawing/present? You may way to put an assertion that `expectedContext == [EAGLContext currentContext]` before the present to see if it fires.

Comment: I believe I'm doing that consistently, but I'll check again.

Comment: I think you might have been right ;-). Checking...

Answer (score 0):

Ben Zotto was right, it was simply a matter of making sure that the correct context is set in every subroutine. Because there are multiple contexts, it was just harder to spot the error. The OpenGL view that made the illegal operation (with the wrong context being set) was not the one that crashed.